# Error loading JS using Backbone widh requireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, backbone.js, requirejs

I have errors loading javascript files with RequireJS and Backbone.

CodeIgniter config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

home.php

```
<script data-main="<?php echo site_url('js/main.js')?>" src="<?php echo site_url('js/libs/require.js')?>"></script>
```

main.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: {
        html5shiv: "libs/html5shiv",
        jquery: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min",
        jqueryui: "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui",
        bootstrap: "libs/bootstrap.min",
        tablesorter: "libs/jquery.tablesorter.min",
        script: "script",
        underscore: "libs/underscore.min",
        backbone: "libs/backbone.min",
        utils: "helpers/utils",
        accountModel: "models/accountModel",
        accountCollection: "collections/accountCollection",
        accountRouter: "routers/accountRouter",
        // Views
        edit: "views/account/account_edit",
        index: "views/account/account_index",
        row: "views/account/account_row",
        //Templates
        'templates': 'templates'
    },
    shim: {
        jqueryui: {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "Jqueryui"
        },
        tablesorter: {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "TableSorter"
        },
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ["jquery"] ,
            exports: "Bootstrap"
        },
        script: {
            deps: ["jquery", "tablesorter", "jqueryui"],
            exports: "Script"
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: "_"
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        }
    }

});

require(["backbone", "underscore", "accountCollection", "accountRouter","bootstrap", "script"],
    function (Backbone, _, AccountCollection, AccountRouter) {
        var accounts = new AccountCollection();
        var router = new AccountRouter({accounts: accounts});
        Backbone.history.start();
    });
```

The files not loading are:

```
http://localhost/project/index.php/js/collections/accountCollection.js
http://localhost/project/index.php/js/routers/accountRouter.js
http://localhost/project/index.php/js/libs/underscore.min.js
http://localhost/project/index.php/js/libs/bootstrap.min.js
http://localhost/project/index.php/js/libs/jquery.tablesorter.min.js
```

Firebug returns: `404 Not Found http://localhost/project/index.php/js/collections/accountCollection.js`

In other pages where I do not use Backbone, RequireJS works just fine and the url to load the js are without index.php

if i change main.js to:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: {
        html5shiv: "http://localhost/project/js/libs/html5shiv",
        jquery: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min",
        jqueryui: "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui",
        bootstrap: "http://localhost/project/js/libs/bootstrap.min",
        tablesorter: "http://localhost/project/js/libs/jquery.tablesorter.min",
        script: "http://localhost/project/js/scripts/script",
        underscore: "http://localhost/project/js/libs/underscore.min",
        backbone: "http://localhost/project/js/libs/backbone.min",
        utils: "http://localhost/project/js/helpers/utils",
        //Files Facebook Collector
        accountModel: "http://localhost/project/js/models/accountModel",
        accountCollection: "http://localhost/project/js/collections/accountCollection",
        accountRouter: "http://localhost/project/js/routers/accountRouter",
        // Views
        edit: "http://localhost/project/js/views/account/account_edit",
        index: "http://localhost/project/js/views/account/account_index",
        row: "http://localhost/project/js/views/account/account_row",
        //Templates
        'templates': 'templates'
    },
    shim: {
        jqueryui: {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "Jqueryui"
        },
        tablesorter: {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "TableSorter"
        },
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ["jquery"] ,
            exports: "Bootstrap"
        },
        script: {
            deps: ["jquery", "tablesorter", "jqueryui"],
            exports: "Script"
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: "_"
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        }
    }

});
```

Only does not load: `http://localhost/project/index.php/js/text.js` (used to load the templates).

```
require(["backbone", "underscore", "accountCollection", "accountRouter","bootstrap", "script"],
    function (Backbone, _, AccountCollection, AccountRouter) {
        var accounts = new AccountCollection();
        var router = new AccountRouter({accounts: accounts});
        Backbone.history.start();
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried an absolute path as baseUrl ? As in: "/project/js"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
baseUrl: "js",
```

Thanks Jonas Geiregat